# When installing additional printer 32-bit drivers fails on Windows 7 64-bit I get the error “Selected printer driver not found”, what should I do?

Tags: windows-7

I've successfully installed Windows 7 (x64) and drivers for my printer hp Laseret 2015d, and have no problem printing with this setup.

There is another PC in the network running XP SP2, and I want to share the printer so that users of that PC can also print.

On W7 I have the option of installing additional printer drivers for other system architectures (Itanium and x86). I've downloaded the most current 32-bit drivers for the printer, but every time I direct the install dialog to the folder containing the drivers, I get the following error message:

Comment: What error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually install the 32bit driver in XP machine then Connect to shared printer. It will not ask for driver again.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a "Selected printer driver not found" error message, too, when trying to access a Canon IP4200 printer from my XP machine.  I tried a lot of options involving .inf files that did not work.  This is what (finally) did:

1. Update the Win7/64 printer driver (Printer Properties | Advanced | Update Printer driver).  Until I did this, I got the same error message no matter what I tried.
2. Delete the Win7/64 printer.
3. Restart the Win7/64 computer and let the printer self-install.
4. Access the Printer Properties | Sharing tab.  Make sure the "Shared" box is checked and then click on install additional drivers; choose to install the x86 driver.
5. On the XP machine, choose "Add Printer" and browse to the sharted printer on the Win7/64 machine.

This is probably how it was intended to work - but didn't without the updated driver.